# WSO2 - unable to update mongoDB collection when passing in input parameter to update search statement

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 and mongoDB, but when trying to use the update statement I keep getting "Error in MongoQuery.runQuery".

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want an API that allows me to update a single row in my collection, based on the parameter I pass in.  In my case I want to update the email for a customer based on the account number I pass in.

based on the WSO2 samples it gives an example to update id when I search on a hard coded string, "Bob".

```xml
 <query id="mongo_update" useConfig="mongo_ds">
      <expression>things.update({name:'Bob'}, {name:'Zack', id: #}, true)</expression>
      <param name="id" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```

but I want to search on ID and pass in the parameter to update, something like this:

```html
 <query id="mongo_update" useConfig="mongo_ds">
      <expression>things.update({accountNo: #}, {primaryEmail:'mynew@email.com'}, true)</expression>
      <param name="id" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
```

However when I do that, I always hit the following exception:

```
                        Source Data Service:-
                    Name: mongodb_prod_DSN
                    Location: /mongodb_prod_DSN.dbs
                    Description: N/A
                    Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
                    Current Request Name: updEmailbyAccountNo
                    Current Params: {accountNo=53223345}
                    Nested Exception:-
                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable execute update operation using query { accountNo : # }
                            at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:354)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
                            at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
                            at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
                            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
                            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
                            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
                            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
                            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
                            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
                            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
                            at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
                            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:61)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
                            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
                            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.IntegratorValve.invoke(IntegratorValve.java:48)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
                            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
                            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
                            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
                            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
                            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
                            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
                            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760)
                            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1719)
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
                    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in MongoQuery.runQuery: Unable execute update operation using query { accountNo : # }
                    DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
```

I've searched the web and other posts, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm sure I've missed something basic, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm too impatient and don't understand how WSO2/jongo implement the update command.

Anyhow I installed RESTHeart: http://restheart.org/  as a work around, it exposes the mongo commands as rest APIs, thus I can call the mongo update api, when I need to update things in mongo.

Hope this is useful for others, and if anyone knows how to get the WSO2/jongo command working properly where we can search on ID and then update the rows that match that Id, it would be much appreciated if you can post the answer here.